# Spring oauth2 Remotetokenservice

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I have 2 microservices that I have created with spring boot. 1 microservice has a oauth2 authentication service and the other is an oauth2 resource server.

The resource server uses RemoteTokenService to check if the access token is valid. This works and when I create a rest endpoint and supply a Principal parameter the principal of the logged in user is supplied. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/user/{id:[0-9]+}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, Principal principal) {
}
```

The thing is that the Principal contains the username and authorities of the logged in user and I also need the user info like id of the user.

I don't want to do an extra rest call to get the user data so I was wandering is there anyway to get the remotetokenservice to return more information?

Answer (score 0):

The `RemoteTokenServices` makes nothing but calling `CheckTokenEndpoint` of Spring Security and return back the map values to the resources server.

If you want to get more information then you have to implement `CheckTokenEndpoint::checkToken` method in the Authentication server.

We managed to solve your problem by having spring-oauth2 with JWT integration. So the Authentication Server generates an access token as a claim (after authentication the user) which can hold more information that could be useful at the Resource server. The resource server in this case didn't need to have a remote call to check the token, but it verify the signature of the JWT to accept the claim.